# Integrating refinerycms with a rails 4.2 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have a rails 4.2 application and during development I came across `refinerycms`. On the website it states it supports rails 4.1 and when I tried a bundle install I had a lot of reference issues.

I was wondering if there is a way to integrate it with rails 4.2 instead of downgrading my app to rails 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Made my Gemfile reference the GitHub project instead of the "latest" version which is `2.1.5`

```
gem 'refinerycms', github: 'refinery/refinerycms', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the docs discuss rails 4.2 at https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms

Comment: Yup, checked the GitHub project and noticed it supports 4.2. Cheers.